# iPhoto 9.5.1 update

Tags: imac, mac-appstore, photos.app

I have been trying to update iPhoto through App Store on my iMac, but I constantly fail. It always downloads the whole package - 1.15GB, then it does its mumbo jumbo, but everytime it looks promising, it shows a red sign - *An error has occurred*.

**Of course I have tried rebooting the computer! :-)**

I have a 2010 iMac with Mavericks installed...anybody encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.storehelper/*` and `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.installer/*`

You might have some sort of permissions problem on the existing copy of iPhoto so you might also try deleting it manually before you download the new one.