# OS X Mavericks: Update from iPhoto 9.4.3 to iPhoto 9.5.1 when unable to do so via Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, photos.app, software-update

am using an OS X Mavericks iPhoto 9.4.3 and trying to install iPhoto 9.5.1 - but when I load up iPhoto 9.4.3, it states that I should update to iPhoto 9.5.1 - I click "Go to Software Update", am booted to the Mac App Store, then it doesn't show iPhoto 9.5.1 as an available download.

I went the route of [Ask Different iPhoto 9.5.1 upgrade thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117696/iphoto-9-5-1-update) and deleted the com.apple.storehelper/* but that didn't help. Then I went and deleted iPhoto.app. Big mistake. Now I'm unable to download the app from the Mac App Store (it states "Newest version of iPhoto is for OS X Yosemite only - want to download the previous version?" I click yes and am told "Mac App Store error (null)" and that's it.

How should I proceed? I was able to find a downloader for iPhoto 9.4.3 from the Apple Support pages - and am hoping that it will at least let me re-install iPhoto 9.4.3, but getting to iPhoto 9.5.1 would be pretty important right about now.

(background story, trying to upgrade library to iPhoto 9.5.1 so I can boot up iPhoto 9.5.1 from another Mac and combine / merge it's iPhoto library and the 9.4.3 iPhoto library -- since I'm doing a massive 3 machine 3 iPhoto library merge + duplicate check work for a friend)

Comment: I assume there's a pressing reason why getting Yosemite isn't an option?

Comment: @user24601 Yes, this machine I'm running on is very slow on OS X Mavericks, and since it's a machine for an import-export company, they can't afford to stop and have me do a re-install. I would, of course like to upgrade everything to OS X Yosemite - but this machine is a 2011 iMac and the Apple repairs company refused to install a SSD to it.

Comment: Alright. Just so you know, there are rumors saying that OS X 10.11 will focus heavily on performance/stability, so you may want to keep an eye out for that when it gets announced in a week and released in the fall.

Comment: @user24601 Definitely. Once the Public Beta pops up, I'll be giving it the whirl. Once people start talking about how it works on 2011 iMacs, I'll see if it's time to upgrade these machines in the fall. It would be swell if this was "Snow Yosemite", a similar version of Mavericks (the optimizations) and Snow Leopard ("no new features, just bug fixes").